# Visual Studio Express Edition to create telco-grade apps

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

Hi guys can I use Visual Studio 2010 express edition to create a telco-grade applications?

Comment: you can use it to produce whatever your imagination can come up with.

Comment: The quality of any Application is down to your design and programming skills

Comment: Define 'Telco-grade'? If I was to use Telstra as a model, that wouldn't amount to much.

Comment: I'm not convinced telco-grade means high levels of quality assurance and quality. Atleast not if you take BT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a text editor like Vi to create a telco-grade (otherwise known as carrier-grade) application, or even Notepad. Being telco-grade has nothing to do with the tools you use to write the software, but the language/compiler/runtime quality, design methodology, testing regime, etc.

You might find it easier using a full version of Visual Studio if the additional capabilities contribute to code quality.

Comment: Yes we're planning to buy the licensed edition but I'm tasked to take a look at the new IDE and all I have now is the express editions.

Comment: @powerbox - if you are planning to buy, then I'd suggest looking at MSDN subscriptions.  You get access to a lot more than just VS, and if you are developing commercial apps those extras are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create commercial applications with the Express Editions, no problem. That is allowed in the licencing conditons. But you need to say what's special about telco-grade apps that might lead other considerations.

Comment: There's no strict definition of telco or carrier grade, but it implies that the application will provide a 24/7 service with no required down time (typically provided by redundancy and automatic falover) and high reliability such as five nines or better.